# Export GAE App Engine Datastore entities to csv

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore

I currently have a list of entities and their properties displayed in an HTML table but I would like to add a capability for users to click a button to download the entity data as a .csv file. What is the best way to go about doing this? I have looked at creating a csv file directly from the HTML table with Javascript, but this won't be compatible across all browsers. Is there an easy way to have the Datastore write out csv files?

Comment: i did it with jExcelAPI...

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee you can export the data in user request timeout you can create it by doing it in a handler just querying and creating the csv then send appropriate headers to start a download but there might be time that these will become big exports that you should just use a task queue.

The task would query and write to blobstore or gcs then when ready you notify user its ready for download. You can also make this push with channel api so it's instant. So flow would be:

```
click Export Button
create a channel connection and show a loading icon
run the task with channel id and needed info to create it
when done send message to channel
onReceive download complete do a location.href=your.csv
```

This is just a sample, you can improve it that it does not require for you to wait and show a link when its refreshed or something.